# Couldn't install Argon2 on JRuby

Tags: hash, rubygems, jruby, argon2-ffi

I am trying to install argon2 gem on JRuby 9.1.13,
Here is the gem's [homepage](https://github.com/technion/ruby-argon2).
So I run gem install argon2
and got the error

```
Fetching: argon2-1.1.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing argon2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/jruby-9.1.13.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/argon2-1.1.2/
ext/argon2_wrap
C:/jruby-9.1.13.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180326-5312-1uqpyqe.rb extconf.rb
```

I understand that it has something to do with JRuby as I tried to install it on MRI Ruby and succeed.

As per the documentation it was tested on JRuby

> Tested platforms are MRI Ruby 2.2, 2.3 and JRuby 9000. No assertions are made on other platforms.

Am I doing it wrong? Or are there any alternative gems for implementing argon2 on JRuby?

Comment: The gem's readme further states that [Windows is not a supported platform](https://github.com/technion/ruby-argon2#platform-issues).  So unless you install Windows Subsystem for Linux (aka Ubuntu on Windows) or a virtual machine with Linux, you're basically out of luck there.

Comment: Yes Jyrki, I just found out a while ago. Thanks for answering :)